# How to stop caret blinking in Draft.js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, draftjs, draft-js-plugins

I wanted to stop the caret from blinking in case of readonly mode. Is there a way to achieve it?
I tried setting `animation` property in `.public-DraftEditor-content` but doesn't seem to work.

I don't want to hide the cursor hence making it transparent is not the solution I'm looking for. I just want it to be static and not blink when content is non-editable.